# Can't center navbar in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using this bootstrap code and can't make it to center...

Trying: `float: center, text-align: center` but it doesn't work

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: what are you trying to center? the links? logo? or both?

Comment: Both, its flotaing left by default

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using can you add it to fiddle or as working snippet

Comment: latest 4.1.x...

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-content: center;` to your **navbarNav** id.

Comment: googled that also, doesnt work

Comment: If you want your logo and nav list in the center you have to insert the logo inside your **navbarNav** id. Also use `justify-content: center` in the id. See an example here https://jsfiddle.net/4m5y8tqv/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a helper class for that to add to the `navbar` which is

> `justify-content-center`

Here's a link to the documenation: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick. Take a look at the code below:

```css
.navbar-nav {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}

.navbar-brand {
    margin-top: -2px; /* to set it to the same position (height) as the nav-items */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You have to switch to the expanded view (Full page) to see the result.

Comment: Not my question, but thanks for showing us this.

Comment: this is the best solution by far - i've learnt something new - i've struggled with this before

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
```

replace this line with below line

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light text-center" style="display:block;">
```

I hope it's working fine.